# How to add and commit files to SVN Server using SSIS Package

Tags: svn, ssis

I am adding and committing files created by SSIS to SVN Server manually. The new requirement is to make it part of SSIS package.

Is there any option I can create batch files to use them in the Execute Process Task in SSIS?

Comment: An SSIS project creates .dtsx files. Currently, you are manually adding and committing these newly created SSIS packages to your source control system, SVN, as part of the development process. The desire is to have a step within the SSIS package itself that add/commits itself to SVN? If that is a correct understanding, a followup question will be - what happens in production?

Comment: We have SQL Server Agent job which is scheduled to run the SSIS package. The output of the job is flat file. I always add/commit this flat file to SVN Server manually, but I want to add/commit the flat file to SVN Server automatically by adding Execute Process Task( to the SSIS package).  The Execute process task will call a batch file. I have experience creating batch files to delete, zip and FTP files, but I don't really know how to write the code for this one. If you give me example it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You'd like to version control the output of an SSIS package? Not the package itself but the actual *output*?

Comment: Yes I want to version control the output of the SSIS Package, not the package itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create batch files from an SSIS script task (i.e. Using C#) and then call it afterwards.

Another option could be to have a single batch file that always adds all files in the svn working directory and execute that. That way you don't need to generate a new batch file each time.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the account running the ETL is able to talk to subversion and has already done a checkout on wherever the ETL is going to place the file (and of course that you have the subversion commandline tools involved).

Breaking your process down, you have a new file you need to [Add](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) and then [commit/check in](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html)

I'm lazy and would create a batch file but this can be done via Execute Process Tasks. Besides laziness, creating as a batch file will allow you to test it outside of the SSIS process in case there's issues.

Create a new batch file called AddAndCommit.bat  Place this

```
svn add %1
svn ci -F %1 -m "Auto commit via SSIS"
```

You Execute Process Task should then pass the fully qualified path to the output file as an argument to the above batch file.

You might need to provide a fully qualified path to the subversion executable, I apologize but I don't have a svn installation to test against.